Can a multiclass warlock/barbarian use Eldritch Smite while raging
The rage feature says

If you are able to cast spells, you can’t cast them or concentrate on them while raging.

And Eldritch Smite says

Once per turn when you hit a creature with your pact weapon, you can expend a warlock spell slot to deal an extra 1d8 force damage to the target, plus another 1d8 per level of the spell slot, and you can knock the target prone if it is Huge or smaller.

I'm thinking it works fine RAW as Eldritch Smite isn't listed as a spell, but I'm also not certain as it DOES require you to expend a spell slot.

Wait, I didn't look hard enough. This is essentially just a reskinned Divine Smite which we already have an answer for.
